# previousLocationInView, clarification needed

Tags: ios

As part of the following method, i can ask recorgnier object of type UISwipeGestureRecognizer*

```
- (void) handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
```

About its current location

```
CGPoint currentLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self];
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html), i should also be able to get

```
CGPoint previousLocation = [recognizer previousLocationInView:self];
```

This method, however, is not available. What am i missing please?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain previous location by using

```
[recognizer locationOfTouch:<#(NSUInteger)#> inView:<#(UIView *)#>]
```

I think that previousLocation is deprecated for GR, or exactly for SwipeGR

Answer (score 0):

I too Faced the same problem..

I used UITouch object to get the previousLocationInView

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
CGPoint pre_moveLocation ;
UITouch *theTouch =[touches anyObject];
pre_moveLocation =[theTouch previousLocationInView:imageView;
}
```